# Processing XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I've managed to create an XML document using PHP. I now want to use PHP to loop through the xml document and display it appropriately. Here is the code I have already but does not seem to work.

PHP loop

```
<?php 
            $rss2 = simplexml_load_file('food.xml');
                print "<h3>XML document processed with PHP</h3>";
            foreach ($rss2->xml->item as $item){
                print "Title: ". $item->name."<br>";
                print "Link: <a href=".$item->link.">".$item->link."</a><br>";
                print "Description: ". $item->description."<br>";
                print "<hr />";
            }
?>
```

XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
  <item>
    <name>Food home page</name>
    <link>http://www.food.com/</link>
    <description>home cooking inspiration</description>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Popular recipes</name>
    <link>http://www.food.com/recipes-popular</link>
    <description>Popular home food recipes</description>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Pulled pork</name>
    <link>http://www.food.com/recipe/pulled-pork-crock-pot-131018</link>
    <description>Crock pot pulled pork recipe</description>
  </item>
</xml>
```

Anyone's help will be appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: The document element of an RSS should be `rss` and not `xml`. *btw*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a debugger or simply running `var_dump` on your `$rss2` variable you can see that the only property on `$rss2` is called `item`. My takeaway from that is that simplexml somehow groups items by element name and exposes them in an array like manner. However, that's probably [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) if you wish to learn more.

For a cleaner way to loop over your data I would recommend writing your for loop as `foreach ($rss2 as $element_name => $item)` (`$element_name` will hold the element name, i.e. `item`, which could be meaningful in a situation where your XML schema allows other elements at root level), although `foreach ($rss2->item as $item)` works equally well.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite

```
foreach ($rss2->xml->item as $item)
```

to

```
foreach ($rss2->item as $item)
```

$rss2 is already at the xml tag level as it goes to the top level tag. In effect you were saying "xml - xml - item" which doesn't exist in your data file.